Is mineral quartz resistant to sulfuric acid?
We intend to use mineral quartz as a filler in a composite grout.
"Quartz, known as silica or silicon dioxide, this mineral is allochromatic with a hardness of 7 on the Mohs scale, specific gravity of 2.65 g/cm³, and a melting point of approximately 1,720°C."
This pure quartz is widely available in my country in various granule sizes, sold with the above description.
The resin used will be an epoxy phenol novolac by Huntsman, cured with a formulated polyamine adduct (hardener). These products are recommended by the manufacturer for this use case.
My question is regarding the mineral quartz.
This floor will be in constant contact with spills of sulfuric acid 98% at room temperature, which will in due time be "washed" by rainwater, causing an exothermic reaction.
The function of this ~50mm grout layer is to protect and function as a sacrificial layer over the composite (pure resin with reinforcement) in order to further preserve the waterproof coating.
Some wear and corrosion are expected in this layer over the years, but I wonder if the quartz will be a problem and easily susceptible to corrosion by the concentrated and diluted acid. Something to consider further is the exothermic reaction upon the contact with rain.

Quartz, just like glass, doesn't react with sulfuric acid at all.

Your whole idea here is somewhat unclear, though, and doesn't sound good. You don't leave conc.  H2SO4 spills to be washed away by rain.

@Mithoron Thanks for the input. In the industry, at least in my country, it is a reality that 98% sulfuric acid tanks are often located outside, protected by a containment basin made of concrete. Sometimes they are coated with epoxy or some other solution, sometimes not, and thus suffer severe corrosion.
Spillage occurs when loading the tank or due to equipment malfunction). Spillage is collected but often it is just left as is for days.
This is a reality.
My question regards wether adding mineral quartz to composite will improve or degrade performance.

Quartz is a special crystallized form of silica $\ce{SiO2}$. As all forms of silica, quartz is resistant to sulfuric acid, at all concentrations and all temperature. If you want a proof of this chemical resistance, it can be mentioned that fused silica ($\ce{SiO2}$) is often used to make beakers and other glassware resistant to concentrated acids like sulfuric acid, whatever the temperature. It should also be mentioned that silica (and quartz of course) is slightly and slowly attacked by hydroxides or bases like $\ce{NaOH}$, particularly at high temperatures with molten $\ce{NaOH}$ (above $318$°C). The reaction of $\ce{NaOH}$ on silica is slow, even at high temperature. It produces a sodium silicate, which can be rather slowly dissolved into water.

Thank you for your reply; it's definitely something to consider.
Especially concerning this specific problem I need to solve, where one containment basin for a sulfuric acid tank is side by side with another containing 50% NaOH.
The containment tanks are separated by a wall, but spillage from one side to the other can occur.
I will wait for others to give input, and later today I'll come back here to mark your reply. Thanks again.
